# AlmaLinux Postgersql installation error

Tags: software-installation, postgresql, error-handling, alma-linux

I've followed the instruction at [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) to install Postgresql at AlmaLinux. But the error persists.

```
$ sudo yum install -y postgresql15-server
```

The error:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64                564  B/s | 146  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'pgdg96':
  - Status code: 404 for https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 87.238.57.227)

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgdg96': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I've found the *repomd.xml* file at
https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/common/pgdg-centos8-sysupdates/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml

but when

```
sudo yum install -y  https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/common/pgdg-centos8- 
sysupdates/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

it returned the same error.

### Checking the HREL version

$ hostnamectl

```
Static hostname: 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 08e54cb75f274905b94df9482e6eb3ba
       Boot ID: cf3ba98fd2d64b57acae1711a4dee431
Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: **AlmaLinux 8.7** (Stone Smilodon)
   CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos
        Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

### Update:

Now as I've changed the RHEL version to 8 at [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) the code provided was almost identical with the same error:

```
sudo dnf install -y      https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64       659  B/s | 146  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'pgdg96':
- Status code: 404 for 
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml  
    Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgdg96': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

[image]

### Update 2

```
$ sudo dnf install --refresh postresql-server
AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS                            7.7 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream                         7.8 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00
AlmaLinux 8 - Extras                            6.3 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
google-chrome                                    25 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00
Panopta Repository                               15 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_  18 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00
PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64         43 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64         19 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64        3.8 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
No match for argument: postresql-server
Error: Unable to find a match: postresql-server
```

Comment: You should indicates how you have declared the `postgresql.org` repository which doesn't seem to belong to an official AlmaLinux repository. The Postgresql indicates for a v8, the installation of `https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`

Comment: You should indicate which version you use. Your question deals with v8 and v9.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, I know nothing of `postgresql.org` repository... could you consult me /direct me of it ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, "You should indicate which version you use." - version of what ?

Comment: The version of RedHat Enterprise Linux. You should go here to have a new version of Postgres for RHEL. https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/ But here, I see a mismatch (url with rhel instead of EL)

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, the command  `cat /etc/redhat-release` returned
`AlmaLinux release 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)`. So, the **RHEL version is 8.7**.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, thanks and see my updates.

Comment: You is the content if `/etc/yum.repos.d` ?

Comment: Result: 
```cd /etc/yum.repos.d
$ ls
almalinux-ha.repo              
almalinux-rt.repo
almalinux-nfv.repo               
almalinux-saphana.repo
almalinux-plus.repo             
almalinux-sap.repo
almalinux-powertools.repo        
panopta.repo
almalinux.repo                  
pgdg-redhat-all.repo
almalinux-resilientstorage.repo```

Comment: Why are you even going this very complicated route? I just tried, and on a fresh Alma 8.7 container, `dnf install --refresh postresql-server` just works. Nothing more to do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I did as you've just recommended. Any hints how to move one with `Error: Unable to find a match: postresql-server` ?

Comment: as said, this was on a clean alma Linux 8.7 container. So, yours is not that. I don't know whether you removed some repositories or something before.