# Failure to install MySQL server at AlmaLinux

Tags: linux, software-installation, mysql, alma-linux

I try to install MySQL server at Almalinux v. 8.7

```
$ sudo dnf install mysql

PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64                 757  B/s | 146  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'pgdg96':
 - Status code: 404 for 
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-8- 
x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 147.75.85.69)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgdg96': Cannot download repomd.xml:
Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

### Checking the HREL version

```
$ hostnamectl

Static hostname: 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 08e54cb75f274905b94df9482e6eb3ba
       Boot ID: cf3ba98fd2d64b57acae1711a4dee431
Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: AlmaLinux 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)
   CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos
        Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

Prior to that I've tried to **[install PostgreSQL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743613/81487) and failed with the same error**.

### Disable pgdg96

as I try `sudo dnf --disable pgdg96` the response was:

```
--enable, --set-enabled and --disable, --set-disabled must be 
used with config-manager command.
```

As i tried with `config-manager` I failed too:

```
 $ sudo yum-config-manager --disablerepo pgdg96                               
sudo: yum-config-manager: command not found
 $ sudo yum-config-manager --disable pgdg96
sudo: yum-config-manager: command not found 
 $ sudo config-manager --disable pgdg96
sudo: config-manager: command not found
 $ sudo config-manager --disablerepo pgdg96
sudo: config-manager: command not found
```

Yet `sudo dnf config-manager --disable pgdg96` worked!

Comment: `pgdg96` that's a custom repo that you have added yourself, and it seemingly doesn't work. Remove it or disable it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks. How to remove it ?

Comment: you can use sudo dnf --disablerepo=pgdg96 to disable the Postgres repo (which doesn't reply) before trying to install mysql/mysqld packages

Comment: @admstg, see my update on disabling.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin then disable it the same way you enabled it. Probably just a file in /etc/yum.repos.d, but who knows what you did!