# Can't start mysql server at AlmaLinux

Tags: mysql, alma-linux

I try to start ***mysql** server* at AlmaLinux:

```
[asigor@89 etc]$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

it seems to me I can't start ***mysqld*** either, when I do:

```
[asigor@89 etc]$ mysqld
2023-05-10T14:47:28.044565Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2023-05-10T14:47:28.044617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2023-05-10T14:47:28.044643Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 279360
2023-05-10T14:47:28.046672Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2023-05-10T14:47:28.046683Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-05-10T14:47:28.049143Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2023-05-10T14:47:28.049221Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-05-10T14:47:28.049356Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  Source distribution.
```

with ***sudo***:

```
[asigor@89 etc]$ sudo mysqld start
2023-05-10T15:07:35.437541Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentica                                                     tion_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use a                                                     uthentication_policy instead.
2023-05-10T15:07:35.437570Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld                                                      (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 279878
2023-05-10T15:07:35.439010Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please r                                                     ead "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-05-10T15:07:35.439051Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-05-10T15:07:35.439143Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld:                                                      Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  Source distribution.
```

Any hints/tips ?

### Update

```
[asigor@89 ~]$ sudo systemctl start mysql
[asigor@89 ~]$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib
[asigor@89 ~]$ journalctl -u mysql.service
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

### Update 2

Following the @"Marcus Mueller" comment:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql
$ sudo journalctl -u mysql.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-05-11 01:00:01 UTC, end at Fri 2023-05-12 07:43:08 UT>
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Started MySQL S>
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: >
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: >
lines 1-4/4 (END)
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-05-11 01:00:01 UTC, end at Fri 2023-05-12 07:43:08 UTC. --
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited,>
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The error: **Failed with result 'exit-code'**.

### Update 3

```
$ sudo journalctl -u mysql.service > journal.txt
```

the log content copied from file:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-05-11 01:00:01 UTC, end at Fri 2023-05-12 10:13:00 UTC. --
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 12 07:42:58 89.162.205.92.host.secureserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

### Update 4

```
$ sudo pgrep mysqld
$ sudo journalctl -u pgrep.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-05-11 01:00:01 UTC, end at Fri 2023-05-12 11:22:12 UT>
-- No entries --
```

### Update 5

I've somehow tried to start mysql but it seems I've failed:

```
systemctl mysqld.service start
```

See the status:

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-16 10:49:21 UTC; 37s ago
  Process: 567142 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.>
 Main PID: 567142 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Comment: Please add the full output of your commands (since you are copying and pasting only part of the logs (the character `>` means that you have to press right key in order to see the following output) ). Anyways, run the commands by using `journalctl -xe --no-pager`, like this `sudo journalctl -xe --no-pager -u mysql`

Answer (score 2):

1. don't run `mysqld` as root. As the error messages actually tell you, that's the reason mysqld shuts down when you use `sudo`. So, no surprise there, read the messages.
2. When running `mysqld` manually as your user `asigor`, it can't create things in /var/lib/mysql/; that's quite reasonable! That's also in the messages:

> Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test

Solution is easy: don't manually start mysqld at all, but use `sudo systemctl start mysql`.  The logs can be viewed through `journalctl -u mysql.service`.

Comment: see my update on your proposal.

Comment: It would be great if you read the output of journalctl and realized you might have to run it with sudo on your own!

Comment: Muller, thanks, see my second Update.

Comment: You somehow managed to cut and paste the output of `journalctl` while leaving out the *exact* parts that might have explained what's going wrong, possibly because it was sending the output through a pager that interacted with your terminal size. Try again, this time redirecting the `journalctl` output into a file and cut/paste *that*.

Comment: @Shadur, see my 3-d update.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin Thanks for the update! Are you per chance already running a separately started mysqld? `sudo pgrep mysqld` might be able to tell you whether that is the case. If that's not the case, we'll have to dig into whether mysqld wrote any logs – that depends on its configuration. First question would then be how you installed mysql.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I indeed tried to install PostGreSQL. See my failed [attempts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743613/almalinux-postgersql-installation-error). See also update 4.

Comment: that's irrelevant to the question of how you installed mysql. I just tried, and `dnf install -y --refresh mysql-server` works, out of the box, on a clean almalinux machine.